# Menotr Questa 10.7a on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to run questa 10.7a on Ubuntu 18.04.

Installation went well and also installed the fpga libraries but when I try to run `./qverify` I get:

```
Error: Unknown platform ''.
Please correct the installation.
```

Despite is not the same problem I've tried installing many libraries of solutions like:

- [How do I run Mentor Modelsim/Questa in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121815/how-do-i-run-mentor-modelsim-questa-in-ubuntu-18-04)
- https://tenthousandfailures.com/blog/2014/2/1/installing-mentor-questa-on-ubuntu
- https://www.anthonyvh.com/2017/10/13/questasim_on_ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `qverify` uses the path from which it is called to guess on which platform it is running. Launching as `./linux_x86_64/bin/qverify -help` works.

Comment: I had the same issue and this works. You can also go ahead and set an alias so that you do not have to type the path out each time and that works. Thanks for the answer 
scafir